# Adding a parameter to Scriptlet function call

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

first question so please be gentle :-)

I'm writing App Script for a Google Doc sidebar. In a modal HTML window, I have the following code:

```js
//In Google Apps Script
function loadMyProgramme(url) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);

  var range = ss.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn())
    .getValues();

  myProgramme = range;
  return myProgramme;
}

//the variable workingFileUrl is setup when the page is loaded and it works fine. When the page loads, the Google Sheets URL is displayed on the page (expected behaviour). 
function getMyWorkingFile() {
  return workingFileUrl;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>My Programme</h1>
  <div id="workingFile">
    <?= getMyWorkingFile(); ?>
  </div>
  <? const myUrl = document.getElementById("workingFile").innerHTML; ?>
    <? const myProg = loadMyProgramme(myUrl); ?>
      <? if (myProg.length >0) { ?>
        <div class="table">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">Seq</div>
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Start</div>
            <div class="cell">Duration</div>
            <div class="cell">Instructions</div>
          </div>
          <? for(var i=0; i<myProg.length; ++i) { ?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell">
                <?= myProg[i][0];?>
              </div>
              <div class="cell">
                <?= myProg[i][1];?>
              </div>
              <div class="cell">
                <?= myProg[i][2];?>
              </div>
              <div class="cell">
                <?= myProg[i][3];?>
              </div>
              <div class="cell">
                <?= myProg[i][4];?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <? } ?>
        </div>
        <? } ?>

</body>

</html>
```

This should return a two-dimensional array object from which I can build out a data table. But I want the "myUrl" parameter to come from the HTML document (the code inside the "workingFile" object) and can get it in Javascript through

```
var myUrl = document.getElementById("workingFile").innerHTML;
```

Is there a way to combine the two and what would that be?

I already tried variations of this to no avail:

```
<? const myProg = loadMyProgramme("?>document.getElementById("workingFile").innerHTML;<? "); ?>
```

Comment: I would need to see more of the templated html.  How are the scriplets being used.  This one `<? const myProg = loadMyProgramme(myUrl); ?>` is a standard scriptlet which does not output content to the page.  So I can't really tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please read about and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks - added some more detail to the code to explain more about what I'm trying to do. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I don't see the element  with id of "workingFile"

Comment: Sorry just added that bit: <div id="workingFile"><?= getMyWorkingFile(); ?></div>. This part works fine and the field displays the Google Sheets URL as expected. I've also managed to use this (via document.getElementById) in another part of the page correctly.

Comment: Please read about makeing a [mcve].  The less we have to do to produce a working example the more likely we are to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

google apps script:

```
function getMyData(url) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  return vs;
}


function launchDataDialog() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let r = ui.prompt("Enter url of Spreadsheet",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  let url;
  if(r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    url = r.getResponseText();
    let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
    t.url = url;//Javascript global variable
    let html = t.evaluate();
    ui.showModelessDialog(html,"Data");
  }
}
```

html: (name: "ah1.html")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = getMyData(url); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The version below does not use a standard ui dialog.

google apps script:

```
function getMyData(obj) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(obj.url);
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  return vs;
}

function launchUrlDialog() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2"),"URL Dialog");
}

function launchDataDialog(url) {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1');
  t.url = url;//passing url to javascript as a global variable from the form obj
  let html = t.evaluate().setWidth(1000);
  ui.showModelessDialog(html, "Data");
}
```

html:

filename: ah1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = getMyData(url); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

filename: "ah2.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      console.log("script");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form>
      <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter URL"/><br><input type="button" value="Test" onClick= "google.script.run.launchDataDialog(this.parentNode)"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful code demo there. I needed something that didn't invoke a dialog but managed to work it out. Plus your code helped with another problem too. Much appreciated :-)